# How to convert a float/double/half to a minifloat the optimal way (improve my already working code)?

Tags: c#, c++, c, performance, floating-point

I've written an IEEE 754 "quarter" 8-bit minifloat in a 1.3.4.−3 format in C#.
It was mostly a fun little side-project, testing whether or not I understand floats.

Actually, though, I find myself using it more than I'd like to admit :) (bandwidth > clock ticks)

Here's my code for converting the minifloat to a 32-bit float:

```
public static implicit operator float(quarter q)
{
    int sign = (q.value & 0b1000_0000) << 24;
    int fusedExponentMantissa = (q.value & 0b0111_1111) << (23 - MANTISSA_BITS);
    
    
    if ((q.value & 0b0111_0000) == 0b0111_0000) // NaN/Infinity
    {
        return asfloat(sign | (255 << 23) | fusedExponentMantissa);
    }
    else // normal and subnormal
    {
        float magic = asfloat((255 - 1 + EXPONENT_BIAS) << 23);
    
        return magic * asfloat(sign | fusedExponentMantissa);
    }
}
```

where quarter.value is the stored byte and "asfloat" is simply `*(float*)&myUInt`.The "magic" number makes use of mantissa overflow in the subnormal case, which affects the f_32 exponent (integer multiplication and mask + add is slower than FPU-switch and float multiplication). I guess one could optimize away the branch, too.

But here comes the problematic code - float_32 to float_8:

```
public static explicit operator quarter(float f)
{
    byte f8_sign      = (byte)((asuint(f) & 0x8000_0000u) >> 24);
    uint f32_exponent = asuint(f) & 0x7F80_0000u;
    uint f32_mantissa = asuint(f) & 0x007F_FFFFu;
    
    
    if (f32_exponent < (120 << 23)) // underflow => preserve +/- 0
    {
        return new quarter { value = f8_sign };
    }
    else if (f32_exponent > (130 << 23)) // overflow => +/- infinity or preserve NaN
    {
        return new quarter { value = (byte)(f8_sign | PositiveInfinity.value | touint8(isnan(f))) };
    }
    else
    {
        switch (f32_exponent)
        {
            case 120 << 23: // 2^(-7) * 1.(mantissa > 0) means the value is closer to quarter.epsilon than 0
            {
                return new quarter { value = (byte)(f8_sign | touint8(f32_mantissa != 0)) };
            }
            case 121 << 23: // 2^(-6) * (1 + mantissa): return +/- quarter.epsilon = 2^(-2) * (0 + 2^(-4)); if the mantissa is > 0.5 i.e. 2^(-6) * max(mantissa, 1.75), return 2^(-2) * 2^(-3) 
            {
                return new quarter { value = (byte)(f8_sign | (Epsilon.value + touint8(f32_mantissa > 0x0040_0000))) };
            }
            case 122 << 23:
            {
                return new quarter { value = (byte)(f8_sign | 0b0000_0010u | (f32_mantissa >> 22)) };
            }
            case 123 << 23:
            {
                return new quarter { value = (byte)(f8_sign | 0b0000_0100u | (f32_mantissa >> 21)) };
            }
            case 124 << 23:
            {
                return new quarter { value = (byte)(f8_sign | 0b0000_1000u | (f32_mantissa >> 20)) };
            }
            default:
            {
                const uint exponentDelta = (127 + EXPONENT_BIAS) << 23;
    
                return new quarter { value = (byte)(f8_sign | (((f32_exponent - exponentDelta) | f32_mantissa) >> 19)) };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... where the function
"asuint" is simply `*(uint*)&myFloat` and
"touint8" is simply `*(byte*)&myBoolean` i.e. `myBoolean ? 1 : 0`.
The first five cases deal with numbers that can only be represented as subnormals in a "quarter".

I want to get rid of the switch at the very least. There's obviously a pattern (same as with float8_to_float32) but I haven't been able to figure out how I could unify the entire switch for days... I tried to google how hardware converts doubles to floats but that yielded no results either.

My requirements are to hold on to the IEEE-754 standard, meaning:
NaN, infinity preservation and clamping to infinity/zero in case of over-/underflow, aswell as rounding to epsilon when the larger type's value is closer to epsilon than 0 (first switch case aswell as the underflow limit in the first if statement).

Can anyone at least push me in the right direction please?

Comment: Do you need to code for under/overflow and NaN?  Or can you simply assume those won't occur?

Comment: The range of the "quarter" is [-15.5, 15.5] with an epsilon of 0.015625 => overflow will certainly occur with f32 -> f8. 
Infinity and NaN preservation is a criteria of IEEE-754, so I would want to keep it.
As for the first switch case, I don't even know whether or not a f64 that is closer to f32.epsilon is rounded to zero or to f32.epsilon. I would like to hold on to that standard, too, as soon as I know what it actually is.

Comment: I would extract the sign, multiply by `2**(3-127)` clamp everything above `asfloat(0x0380_0000)` to that value, then shift what you get 19 bits to the right and join the sign bit (this will always truncate to zero instead of rounding-to-nearest/halfway-to-even. And you probably need to check for NaNs as well).

Comment: Normally, working code is best reviewed on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  You should not choose C and C++ and C# as languages.  The code you show clearly isn't C — I think it is C#.  Cross-tagging with C and C++ is bad enough; adding C# with either is worse.  Strong recommendation: don't do it.  Or explicitly ask for help with differences between two languages, noting that C and C++ are very different languages, albeit with a common ancestor.

Comment: Note that in C# there are two methods to convert to/from `float`<->`int`: `BitConverter.Int32BitsToSingle` and `BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits`, so you don't need unsafe code.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler
Thanks for directing me to Code Review - I wasn't aware of that site. As for referencing three languages: I am well aware of the huge differences between them. I use all three of them regularly. I was suggesting that I accept answers written in any of these (note that I didn't reference Java, which is the most similar to C#). An apart from the function declaration, the code is literally portable to C and C++ apart from underscore separators - binary literals are supported with gcc.

Comment: @xanatos "asuint" is way shorter than "BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits" and part of a library that I statically import. Apart from that, that function does the exact same thing https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs.
"Not needing unsafe code" is a meaningless statement - especially if I'm only dereferencing a 4 byte type as a 4 byte type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...And after some time and in the spirit of transparent progression, I want to show the final version, since I believe to have found the optimal implementation; more later.

First off, here it is (the code should speak for itself, which is why it is this "much"):

```
unsafe struct quarter
{
    const bool IEEE_754_STANDARD = true;                                                                            //standard: true
    const bool SIGN_BIT = IEEE_754_STANDARD || true;                                                                //standard: true
    const int BITS = 8 * sizeof(byte);                                                                              //standard: 8
    const int EXPONENT_BITS = 3 + (SIGN_BIT ? 0 : 1);                                                               //standard: 3
    const int MANTISSA_BITS = BITS - EXPONENT_BITS - (SIGN_BIT ? 1 : 0);                                            //standard: 4
    const int EXPONENT_BIAS = -(((1 << BITS) - 1) >> (BITS - (EXPONENT_BITS - 1)));                                 //standard: -3
    const int MAX_EXPONENT = EXPONENT_BIAS + ((1 << EXPONENT_BITS) - 1) - (IEEE_754_STANDARD ? 1 : 0);              //standard: 3
    const int SIGNALING_EXPONENT = (MAX_EXPONENT - EXPONENT_BIAS + (IEEE_754_STANDARD ? 1 : 0)) << MANTISSA_BITS;   //standard: 0b0111_0000                     

    const int F32_BITS = 8 * sizeof(float);         
    const int F32_EXPONENT_BITS = 8;
    const int F32_MANTISSA_BITS = 23;
    const int F32_EXPONENT_BIAS = -(int)(((1L << F32_BITS) - 1) >> (F32_BITS - (F32_EXPONENT_BITS - 1)));
    const int F32_MAX_EXPONENT = F32_EXPONENT_BIAS + ((1 << F32_EXPONENT_BITS) - 1 - 1);
    const int F32_SIGNALING_EXPONENT = (F32_MAX_EXPONENT - F32_EXPONENT_BIAS + 1) << F32_MANTISSA_BITS;
    const int F32_SHL_LOSE_SIGN = (F32_BITS - (MANTISSA_BITS + EXPONENT_BITS));
    const int F32_SHR_PLACE_MANTISSA = MANTISSA_BITS + ((1 + F32_EXPONENT_BITS) - (MANTISSA_BITS + EXPONENT_BITS));
    const int F32_MAGIC = (((1 << F32_EXPONENT_BITS) - 1) - (1 + EXPONENT_BITS)) << F32_MANTISSA_BITS;

    byte _value;

    static quarter Epsilon => new quarter { _value = 1 };
    static quarter MaxValue => new quarter { _value = (byte)(SIGNALING_EXPONENT - 1) };
    static quarter NaN => new quarter { _value = (byte)(SIGNALING_EXPONENT | 1) };
    static quarter PositiveInfinity => new quarter { _value = (byte)SIGNALING_EXPONENT };

    static uint asuint(float f) => *(uint*)&f;
    static float asfloat(uint u) => *(float*)&u;
    static byte tobyte(bool b) => *(byte*)&b;


    static float ToFloat(quarter q, bool promiseInRange)
    {
        uint fusedExponentMantissa = ((uint)q._value << F32_SHL_LOSE_SIGN) >> F32_SHR_PLACE_MANTISSA;
        uint sign = ((uint)q._value >> (BITS - 1)) << (F32_BITS - 1);
    
        if (!promiseInRange)
        {
            bool nanInf = (q._value & SIGNALING_EXPONENT) == SIGNALING_EXPONENT;
            uint ifNanInf = asuint(float.PositiveInfinity) & (uint)(-tobyte(nanInf));
        
            return (nanInf ? 1f : asfloat(F32_MAGIC)) * asfloat(sign | fusedExponentMantissa | ifNanInf);
        }
        else
        {
            return asfloat(F32_MAGIC) * asfloat(sign | fusedExponentMantissa);
        }
    }

    static quarter ToQuarter(float f, bool promiseInRange)
    {
        float inRange = f * (1f / asfloat(F32_MAGIC));
        uint q = asuint(inRange) >> (F32_MANTISSA_BITS - (1 + EXPONENT_BITS));
        uint f8_sign = asuint(f) >> (F32_BITS - 1);
    
        if (!promiseInRange)
        {
            uint f32_exponent = asuint(f) & F32_SIGNALING_EXPONENT;
            bool overflow = f32_exponent > (uint)(-F32_EXPONENT_BIAS + MAX_EXPONENT << F32_MANTISSA_BITS); 
            bool notNaNInf = f32_exponent != F32_SIGNALING_EXPONENT; 
            f8_sign ^= tobyte(!notNaNInf);
            if (overflow & notNaNInf)
            {
                q = PositiveInfinity._value;
            }
        }

        f8_sign <<= (BITS - 1);

        return new quarter{ _value = (byte)(q ^ f8_sign) };
    }
}
```

Turns out that in fact, the reverse operation of converting the mini-float to a 32 bit float by multiplying with a magic constant is also the reverse operation of a multiplication (wow...): a floating point division by that constant.
Luckily "by that constant" and not the other way around; we can calculate the reciprocal at compile time and multiply by it instead. This only fails, as with the reverse operation, when converting to- and from 'INF' and 'NaN'. Absolute overflow with any biased 32 exponent with `exponent % (MAX_EXPONENT + 1) != 0` is not translated into 'INF' and positive 'INF' is translated into negative 'INF'.

Although this enables some optimizations through the bool paramater, this mostly just reduces code size and more importantly (especially for SIMD versions, where small data types really shine) reduces the need for constants. Speaking of SIMD: This scalar version can be optimized a little by using SSE/SSE2 intrinsics.
The (disabled) optimizations (would) run completely in parallel to the floating point multiplication followed by a shift, taking a total of 5 to 6+ clock cycles (very CPU dependant), which is astonishingly close to native hardware instructions (~4 to 5 clock cycles).

Answer (score 2):

This may not be optimal, but it uses strictly conforming C code except as noted in the first comment, so no pointer aliasing or other manipulation of the bits of a floating-point object. A thorough test program is included.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*  Notes on portability:

        uint8_t is an optional type.  Its use here is easily replaced by
        unsigned char.

        Round-to-nearest is required in FloatToMini.

        Floating-point must be base two, and the constant in the
        Dekker-Veltkamp split is hardcoded for IEEE-754 binary64 but could be
        adopted to other formats.  (Change the exponent in 0x1p48 to the number
        of bits in the significand minus five.)
*/


/*  Convert a double to a 1-3-4 floating-point format.  Round-to-nearest is
    required.
*/
static uint8_t FloatToMini(double x)
{
    //  Extract the sign bit of x, moved into its position in a mini-float.
    uint8_t s = !!signbit(x) << 7;
    x = fabs(x);

    /*  If x is a NaN, return a quiet NaN with the copied sign.  Significand
        bits are not preserved.
    */
    if (x != x)
        return s | 0x78;

    /*  If |x| is greater than or equal to the rounding point between the
        maximum finite value and infinity, return infinity with the copied sign.
        (0x1.fp0 is the largest representable significand, 0x1.f8 is that plus
        half an ULP, and the largest exponent is 3, so 0x1.f8p3 is that
        rounding point.)
    */
    if (0x1.f8p3 <= x)
        return s | 0x70;

    //  If x is subnormal, encode with zero exponent.
    if (x < 0x1p-2 - 0x1p-7)
        return s | (uint8_t) nearbyint(x * 0x1p6);

    /*  Round to five significand bits using the Dekker-Veltkamp Split.  (The
        cast eliminates the excess precision that the C standard allows.)
    */
    double d = x * (0x1p48 + 1);
    x = d - (double) (d-x);

    /*  Separate the significand and exponent.  C's frexp scales the exponent
        so the significand is in [.5, 1), hence the e-1 below.
    */
    int e;
    x = frexp(x, &e) - .5;

    return s | (e-1+3) << 4 | (uint8_t) (x*0x1p5);
}


static void Show(double x)
{
    printf("%g -> 0x%02" PRIx8 ".\n", x, FloatToMini(x));
}


static void Test(double x, uint8_t expected)
{
    uint8_t observed = FloatToMini(x);
    if (expected != observed)
    {
        printf("Error, %.9g (%a) produced 0x%02" PRIx8
            " but expected 0x%02" PRIx8 ".\n",
            x, x, observed, expected);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    //  Set the value of an ULP in [1, 2).
    static const double ULP = 0x1p-4;

    //  Test all even significands with normal exponents.
    for (double s = 1; s < 2; s += 2*ULP)
        //  Test with trailing bits less than or equal to 1/2 ULP in magnitude.
        for (double t = -ULP / (s == 1 ? 4 : 2); t <= +ULP/2; t += ULP/16)
            //  Test with all normal exponents.
            for (int e = 1-3; e < 7-3; ++e)
                //  Test with both signs.
                for (int sign = -1; sign <= +1; sign += 2)
                {
                    //  Prepare the expected encoding.
                    uint8_t expected =
                            (0 < sign ? 0 : 1) << 7
                        |   (e+3) << 4
                        |   (uint8_t) ((s-1) * 0x1p4);
                    Test(sign * ldexp(s+t, e), expected);
                }

    //  Test all odd significands with normal exponents.
    for (double s = 1 + 1*ULP; s < 2; s += 2*ULP)
        //  Test with trailing bits less than or equal to 1/2 ULP in magnitude.
        for (double t = -ULP/2+ULP/16; t < +ULP/2; t += ULP/16)
            //  Test with all normal exponents.
            for (int e = 1-3; e < 7-3; ++e)
                //  Test with both signs.
                for (int sign = -1; sign <= +1; sign += 2)
                {
                    //  Prepare the expected encoding.
                    uint8_t expected =
                            (0 < sign ? 0 : 1) << 7
                        |   (e+3) << 4
                        |   (uint8_t) ((s-1) * 0x1p4);
                    Test(sign * ldexp(s+t, e), expected);
                }

    //  Set the value of an ULP in the subnormal range.
    static const double subULP = ULP * 0x1p-2;

    //  Test all even significands with the subnormal exponent.
    for (double s = 0; s < 0x1p-2; s += 2*subULP)
        //  Test with trailing bits less than or equal to 1/2 ULP in magnitude.
        for (double t = s == 0 ? 0 : -subULP/2; t <= +subULP/2; t += subULP/16)
        {
            //  Test with both signs.
            for (int sign = -1; sign <= +1; sign += 2)
            {
                //  Prepare the expected encoding.
                uint8_t expected =
                        (0 < sign ? 0 : 1) << 7
                    |   (uint8_t) (s/subULP);
                Test(sign * (s+t), expected);
            }
        }

    //  Test all odd significands with the subnormal exponent.
    for (double s = 0 + 1*subULP; s < 0x1p-2; s += 2*subULP)
        //  Test with trailing bits less than or equal to 1/2 ULP in magnitude.
        for (double t = -subULP/2 + subULP/16; t < +subULP/2; t += subULP/16)
        {
            //  Test with both signs.
            for (int sign = -1; sign <= +1; sign += 2)
            {
                //  Prepare the expected encoding.
                uint8_t expected =
                        (0 < sign ? 0 : 1) << 7
                    |   (uint8_t) (s/subULP);
                Test(sign * (s+t), expected);
            }
        }

    //  Test at and slightly under the point of rounding to infinity.
    Test(+15.75, 0x70);
    Test(-15.75, 0xf0);
    Test(nexttoward(+15.75, 0), 0x6f);
    Test(nexttoward(-15.75, 0), 0xef);

    //  Test infinities and NaNs.
    Test(+INFINITY, 0x70);
    Test(-INFINITY, 0xf0);
    Test(+NAN, 0x78);
    Test(-NAN, 0xf8);

    Show(0);
    Show(0x1p-6);
    Show(0x1p-2);
    Show(0x1.1p-2);
    Show(0x1.2p-2);
    Show(0x1.4p-2);
    Show(0x1.8p-2);
    Show(0x1p-1);
    Show(15.5);
    Show(15.75);
    Show(16);
    Show(NAN);

    Show(1./6);
    Show(1./3);
    Show(2./3);
}
```

Comment: @chux: Done, thanks. Can’t imagine what led me to think `signbit` returned a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I will be testing it in 10-ish hours :)
Just to note: using pointers here is compiled away anyway. Well... a float MIGHT get moved from an XMM register to a general purpose register (See Agner Fog's "Optimizing cpp" manual on page 42). I'd have to see the source of C's float bit manipulation lib but it LOOKS less optimal. And things like checking agains NaN are better done on an int32_t representation since it takes one and not three clock cycles. Apart from this trivia, your solution unswitches mine, so it might be the way to go apart from the things mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to answer my own question... But this may still not be the optimal solution.

Although @Eric Postpischil's solution uses an established algorithm, it is not very well suited for minifloats, since there are so few denormals in 4 mantissa bits. Additionally, the overhead of multiple float arithmetic operations - and because of the actual code behind `frexp` in particular, it only has one branch less (or two when inlined and optimized) than my original solution and is also not that great in regards to instruction level parallelism.

So here's my current solution:

```cs
public static explicit operator quarter(float f)
{
    byte f8_sign      = (byte)((asuint(f) >> 31) << 7);
    uint f32_exponent = (asuint(f) >> 23) & 0x00FFu;
    uint f32_mantissa = asuint(f) & 0x007F_FFFFu;


    if (f32_exponent < 120) // underflow => preserve +/- 0
    {
        return new quarter { value = f8_sign };
    }
    else if (f32_exponent > 130) // overflow => +/- infinity or preserve NaN
    {
        return new quarter { value = (byte)(f8_sign | PositiveInfinity.value | touint8(isnan(f))) };
    }
    else
    {
        int cmp = 125 - (int)f32_exponent;
        int cmpIsZeroOrNegativeMask = (cmp - 1) >> 31;
                
        int denormalExponent = andnot(0b0001_0000 >> cmp, cmpIsZeroOrNegativeMask);         // special case 121: sets it to quarter.Epsilon
        denormalExponent += touint8((f32_exponent == 121) & (f32_mantissa >= 0x0040_0000)); // case 121: 2^(-6) * (1 + mantissa): return +/- quarter.Epsilon = 2^(-2) * 2^(-4); if the mantissa is >= 0.5 return 2^(-2) * 2^(-3) 
        denormalExponent |= touint8((f32_exponent == 120) & (f32_mantissa != 0));           // case 120: 2^(-7) * 1.(mantissa > 0) means the value is closer to quarter.epsilon than 0

        int normalExponent = (cmpIsZeroOrNegativeMask & ((int)f32_exponent - (127 + EXPONENT_BIAS))) << 4;

        int mantissaShift = 19 + andnot(cmp, cmpIsZeroOrNegativeMask);
                

        return new quarter { value = (byte)((f8_sign | normalExponent) | (denormalExponent | (f32_mantissa >> mantissaShift))) };
    }
}
```

But note that the particular `andnot(int a, int b)` function I use returns `a & ~b` and...not `~a & b`.

Thanks for your help :) I'm keeping this open since, as mentioned, this may very well not be the best solution - but at least it's my own...

PS: This is probably a good example for why PREMATURE optimization is bad; Your code is much less readable. Make sure you have the functionality backed up by unit tests and make sure you even need the optimization in the first place.